# Inserting table of chars as key and float as a result into a map from file

Tags: c++, dictionary, file, error-handling

I want to insert values from text file into a map and encountered this error:

> error: array used as initializer
> 1817 |       : first(std::forward<_Args1>(std::get<_Indexes1>(__tuple1))...),

```
fstream DistanceFile;

map<char[2], float> odleglosci;

void loadkeysdistance()
{
    char temp[2];
    string templine = "";
    float tempfloat = 0;
    DistanceFile.open("keys.txt");
    while (!DistanceFile.eof())
    {
        getline(disctionary, templine);
        temp[0] = templine[0];
        temp[1] = templine[2];
        tempfloat = stof(templine.substr(4, templine.length() - 4));
        odleglosci[temp] = tempfloat;
    }
}
```

this is the function i am using and text file "keys.txt" looks like that:

```
A A 0
A B 87.82
A C 51.29
A D 38.10
A E 38.40
A F 57.15
A G 76.20
A H 95.25
```

and so on till it gets to ZZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map<char[2], float> odleglosci;` this does not do what you think it does.

It would try to compare the pointers to the first elements of the arrays, not the content.

`odleglosci[temp] = tempfloat;` does not make sense due to above and triggers a compilation error on clang for somewhat unrelated reason, since you did not post a minimal reproducible example nor the full error, I am not sure what is causing yours exactly.

Anyway, use `std::pair<char,char>` instead.